# From biased coins (and nothing else) to biased coins

Tags: pr.probability, simulation

### Background

We're given a coin that shows heads with an unknown probability, $\lambda$. The goal is to use that coin (and possibly also a fair coin) to build a "new" coin that shows heads with a probability that depends on $\lambda$, call it $f(\lambda)$. This is the *Bernoulli factory problem* (Keane and O'Brien 1994).

### Main Question

**Prove or disprove:** Let $f:(D\subseteq [0, 1])\to [0,1]$.  Given a coin that shows heads with probability $\lambda$ (which can be 0 or 1), it is possible to toss heads with probability $f(\lambda)$ using the coin and no other sources of randomness (and, thus, $f$ is *strongly simulable*) **if and only if**—

- $f$ is constant on its domain, or is continuous and polynomially bounded on its domain (*polynomially bounded* means, both $f$ and $1-f$ are bounded below by min($x^n$, $(1-x)^n$) for some integer $n$ [Keane and O'Brien 1994]), and
- $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are each 0, 1, or undefined, and
- if $f(0) = 0$ or $f(1) = 0$ or both, then there is a polynomial $g(x):[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with computable coefficients, such that $g(0) = f(0)$ and $g(1) = f(1)$ whenever 0 or 1, respectively, is in the domain of f, and such that $g(x)>f(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain of f, except at 0 and 1, and
- if $f(0) = 1$ or $f(1) = 1$ or both, then there is a polynomial $h(x):[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with computable coefficients, such that $h(0) = f(0)$ and $h(1) = f(1)$ whenever 0 or 1, respectively, is in the domain of f, and such that $g(x)<f(x)$ for every $x$ in the domain of f, except at 0 and 1.

A condition such as "0 is not in the domain of $f$, or $f$ can be extended to a Lipschitz continuous function on $[0, \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$" does not work.  A counterexample is $f(x)=(\sin(1/x)/4+1/2)\cdot(1-(1-x)^n)$ for $n\ge 1$, which is strongly simulable at 0 despite not being Lipschitz at 0.  ($(1-x)^n$ is the probability of the biased coin showing zero $n$ times in a row.)

The rest of this page will detail the problem.

### Simulable and strongly simulable functions

There are two kinds of factory functions:

- A function $f(\lambda)$ is *simulable* if an algorithm exists to toss heads with probability $f(\lambda)$ given a coin with probability of heads $\lambda$ (the "biased coin") as well as a fair coin.
- A function $f(\lambda)$ is *strongly simulable* if an algorithm exists to toss heads with probability $f(\lambda)$ given **only** a coin with probability of heads $\lambda$.

Every strongly simulable function is simulable, but not vice versa.

In fact, Keane and O'Brien (1994) showed already that $f(\lambda)$ is strongly simulable if $f$ is simulable and neither 0 nor 1 is in $f$'s domain (that is, if the biased coin doesn't show heads every time or tails every time).  And it's also easy to show that if $f$ is strongly simulable, then $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ must each be 0, 1, or undefined.

However, it's not so trivial to find the exact class of strongly simulable functions when $f$'s domain includes 0, 1, or both.

As one illustration of this, the proof of Keane and O'Brien relies on generating a geometric random variate and using that variate to control which "part" of the target function $f(\lambda)$ to simulate.   This obviously works on all of [0, 1] if the algorithm uses both the biased coin and a separate fair coin.  However, if only the biased coin is used in the algorithm, the geometric random variate is generated using fair bits via the von Neumann method, which however will never terminate if $\lambda$ is either 0 or 1. In addition, a [**result I found**](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernsupp.html#Which_functions_don_t_require_outside_randomness_to_simulate) gives sufficient conditions for being strongly simulable when $f$'s domain includes 0, 1, or both.  Its proof proceeds by showing, among other things, that the Bernoulli factory for $f$ must flip the input coin and get 0 and 1 before it simulates any fair coin flips via the von Neumann trick.

### References

- Keane, M. S., and O'Brien, G. L., "A Bernoulli factory", *ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation* 4(2), 1994.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\frac13(1-x)+\frac23(x)$? That is strongly simulable but does not seem covered by this result.

Comment: @MattF. Your example of $f(x)$ equals neither 0 nor 1 at the endpoints 0 and 1, so it's not strongly simulable on all of $[0, 1]$.  Like all factory functions, though, it's strongly simulable on $(0, 1)$ (letting $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ be undefined).

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue now. That took me a while; I’m not sure if you have a maximal result here, but I think any maximal result will end up pretty hard to read.

Comment: Does $f(0)$ undefined mean that $0$ is not in the domain of $f$ or that the algorithm for making a coin with probability of heads equal to $f(\lambda)$ doesn't halt when $\lambda=0$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla: $f(0)$ undefined means that 0 is not in the domain of $f$, so that whether the algorithm halts when $\lambda=0$ is irrelevant when 0 is not in that domain.